# symfony 4 twig e imagenes

Tags: symfony4

Quiero cargar una imagen simple con twig.

Leyendo el manual de symfony dice que pongamos esto en twig...

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="Symfony!" />
```

bien pues no funciona.

Tengo instalado assets, $ composer require asset

el fichero logo.png se encuentra en la carpeta assets/images/

También he probado a crear una addentry en el fichero webpack.config.js

así:

```
.addEntry('logoBoard', './assets/images/logo.png')
```

pero el fichero no se carga.

El fichero que me crea en public/build/images es logo.ac628998.png, creo que esto es por el addEntry.

He conseguido cargarlo una vez así:

```
<img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo.ac628998.png') }}" alt="Symfony!" />
```

Pero supongo que esta no es la forma correcta...

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
<img src="{{ asset('logo.png', 'imagenlogo') }}" alt="Symfony!" />
```

Las imágenes debes cargarlas en un directorio dentro de la carpeta public. Por ejemplo si utilizas el directorio 'images' para las imágenes crea el directorio siguiente:

```
public/images
```

En config/packages/framework.yaml debes añadir:

```
framework:
    assets:
        packages:
            imagenlogo:
                base_path: 'images'
```

No olvides mover la imagen logo.png a public/images y vaciar la caché antes de recargar la aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por aportar :D Recuerda leer el [tour] y [answer] para aprender más. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias.